# PayPal Subscribe Button invoice over Opencart

Tags: paypal, opencart

I have to set subscibe button - this is easy but I will need my Opencart shop to create 3 invoice for every month after the paypal transaction is done.

Example

Subscibe button - 3 months x 10 EUR
So Opencart can create invoice for 30 EUR on fisrt transaction, but I want to create 3x10... or 2x10 if user doesnt pay the last one?

And to be secure...

Any ideas? or something to read about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this should be solved as easy as possible - if the customer wants a 3 months subscription he has to pay these 3 months in advance against just one invoice. If he doesn't pay, decline the subscription.

If you want to have *recurring* subscription so that user orders 1 month recurring each next month until canceled then you would need to create some cron job that will run each month renewing those recurring subscriptions and also creating invoices for them...